# ../node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js [1] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

As soon as I try to fetch data using `axios.get(url)` an error saying so is thrown. I have tried doing everything. But nothing works. I have been stuck on this for a long time. If someone can help, it will be greatly valued.

Failed to compile.

> ../node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js Error: EPERM: operation
> not permitted, read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***: THE PROBLEM IS FIXED.THE ONLY WAY THIS HAPPENED IS BY RESETTING MY MACHINE AND UPGRADING TO WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE. PREVIOUSLY IT WAS WINDOWS 7 ENTERPRISE